# How to install Cloudflare Origin CA certificate on server Node.js

Tags: node.js, https, dns, cloudflare

I am developing an application with **Node.js** to consume apis. I want to use **Cloudflare** protection services with my server, one of the services is SSL / TLS.

Is it possible to implement the "end to end" certificate that cloudflare gives in an application with Node.js?

I have the **private key** and **origin key** files that Cloudflare gives me for this.

Thx.

Comment: Did you get any answer?